# SharedPreferences, PreferenceActivity problem

Tags: android

I have in my settings.xml two CheckBoxes. 
Each checkboxes has same keys "ShowContactPhotosCheckBoxPref":

```
<PreferenceScreen
            android:title="Appearence"
            android:key="AppearencePref" >
            ......
            <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="Show Contact Photos">
                <CheckBoxPreference 
                    android:title="Show Contact Photos" 
                    android:summary="@string/show_contact_photos_preference"
                    android:defaultValue="true"
                    android:key="ShowContactPhotosCheckBoxPref" />
            </PreferenceCategory>
       ........
</PreferenceScreen>

.......

<PreferenceScreen
            android:title="Contact Options"
            android:key="ContactOtionsPref">
            <PreferenceCategory 
                android:title="Show Contact Photos">
                <CheckBoxPreference 
                    android:title="Show Contact Photos"
                    android:defaultValue="true"
                    android:key="ShowContactPhotosCheckBoxPref" />
            </PreferenceCategory>
......            
</PreferenceScreen>
```

After start app state of chekbox №1 = chekbox №2 = true.
When I click on chekbox №1(state unchecked) and then go to checkbox №2 - state checked, but in my SharedPreferences file state of ShowContactPhotosCheckBoxPref is false.
It is possible to synchronize these chekboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Naming two keys the same in different preferencescreens doesn't mean they are the same key. In fact it is good practice to use unique key names.
Either use a single checkboxpreference or update the settings for each of the two preferences programmatically when they are checked/unchecked.